# Meaning of 'could' when expressing annoyance

Tags: meaning

*You could have told me!*

*Why couldn't she have said something?*

Does 'could' here still indicate possibility? Is this even a legit question? Because no dictionary puts it in the 'past possibility' category.

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Yes, it indicates possibility. However, all it means is that the action *was* possible at the time.

Comment: *You **could** offer that pregnant lady your seat!* refers to an action that ***is*** possible at the time of speaking. Effectively, in the present tense you're being told you ***should*** do the specified action ***now***, whereas the past tense version simply conveys the speaker's negative attitude to the fact that you ***failed*** to do what you should have done (even though it was actually *possible* at the time).

Comment: Thank you Justin and thank you Monica :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dictionary shows that sense of "could:
[American Heritage Dictionary "could"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=could)

1. Used to indicate ability or permission in the past: *I could run faster then. Only men could go to the club in those days.*

Changing "could" to "could have" just makes it perfect aspect.
Whether it's expressing annoyance or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you Jack for making it clear for me! I was under the impression that sense 3 to 6 do not fall under the possibility category: https://ldoceonline.com/dictionary/could